# NPM Install is not installing all of the files like it did previously

Tags: javascript, html, npm

The first folder I installed NPM Install into, it created several folders and files.

```
node_modules
public
src
.DS_Store
package.json
package-lock.json
webpack.config.js
```

After this, npm start worked just fine.

Now I am starting a new project in this lesson, and I had to create a new folder and start over. So I followed the same procedure, now this time it only installed

```
package.json
package-lock.json
```

Nothing else was installed like the previous folder and time.

So now if I try npm start, I get the error MISSING SCRIPT: START

Can someone help me understand why everything isn't getting installed now like it did in the other directory just 15 minutes ago?

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`npm install` only ever installs modules from `package.json` into the `node_modules` folder. You must have done something else before. Looks like it might have been `npx create-react-app`?

Comment: I have used npx create-react-app in the past, but not this time. I am following along with the instructor for this particular lesson. I even went back and looked over how I did it previously and it's the same steps.

Comment: Check the `package.json` from the first time, does it have a `postinstall` script? That would run automatically after `npm install`.

Comment: This package.json file is empty